# How can I declare a variable of self type?

Tags: objective-c, factory-pattern, instancetype

Consider this example of a constructor:

```
+ (instancetype)widgetWithTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    Widget* widget = [[self alloc] init];
    widget.title = title;
    return widget;
}
```

Say I want to dynamically infer the type, so when my subclasses are called with this constructor, they return a `WidgetSubclass*` instead of `Widget*`.

my expectation for `typeOf(self) widget = [[self alloc] init]` throws compiler warnings. So how can I ask the compiler to create a pointer to whatever type is being called, instead of this hardcoded superclass type?
Note that I realize I can make an `initWithTitle:` method and just return `[[self alloc] initWithTitle:title]`, and that's not the point. 
Also note that I realize this will not actually hinder any setting of operations in the subclass- it is just for the sake of the ideal.

-- EDIT --

I should clarify my intention since this question was not warmly received. The goal is just to see if there's a compile-time `typeOf` mechanism I can use to declare objects of my current context's type (the compile-time equivalent of `[self class]`). Think `instancetype objectOfMyOwnKind = ...` or `typeOf(self) anObjectLikeMe = [self copy]` or something.

This is of no practical application necessarily. Purely a curiosity. There is no question about how to implement a proper constructor and I apologize if the constructor thing is a red herring.

Comment: your code is totally fine.

Comment: Do you understand what inheritance is?  (There is no need to do what you want to do.)

Comment: Read the description guys. Yes, the code is fine! Yes, I understand inheritance! This pattern works and has no consequences to the execution of my code. I just wanted to know the mechanism for generating a class of the current class's type (i.e. if there's a typeOf() method for strong references, like there is for the weakSelf pattern). I have used Objective-C for many years and am just fulfilling some tangential curiosity that came up today.

Comment: "So how can I ask the compiler to create a pointer to whatever type is being called, instead of this hardcoded superclass type?" This _does_ create whatever type is being called. This _is not_ hard coded for the superclass.

Comment: Your clarification makes no sense at all. You can't achieve runtime work at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

> ...I want to dynamically infer the type, so when my subclasses are called with this constructor, they return a `WidgetSubclass*` instead of `Widget*`.

They already do, because that's what `instancetype` means: return an instance of the messaged class.

There's no need to "dynamically type" this variable.* Why?

There's no need because the superclass (which is defining this method) *should not* have specific knowledge of its subclasses. The only reason to type the pointer to refer to a subclass would be to use subclass-specific methods. This is -- at best -- a terrible idea.

Since there is no need, there is no way to do what you're asking.

The superclass is a valid and correct type for this variable. If you want a more general type, you will have to use `id`.

---

*Or any other variable (in a superclass's method) pointing to an instance of the current class.

Answer (score -1):

Whoever is down voting the question should consider whether they actually understand what is being asked.

This might do the trick for you:

```
BaseClass *instance;
instance = [[self class] new];
instance.title = @"...";
```

Comment: I appreciate that you fully read the description and understand my position. This code you've provided is the same as mine above though. And it does work well and is the de-facto way of implementing a factory method in Objective-C! It just doesn't answer the particular nuance I was searching for.

Comment: Just quoting from your question above `but I want to dynamically infer the type, so when my subclasses are called with this constructor, they return a WidgetSubclass* instead of Widget*.`. Isn't it what your code is already achieving?

Comment: Well, kind of. When a subclass `FooWidget` is instantiated with the superclass method `widgetWithTitle`, it will still be typed as `FooWidget` because `[[self alloc] init...]` will instantiate the proper class for the context. I am just curious if I can use the compiler to declare a variable as the type of my current class. I think the constructor example is giving folks huge Red Herring though. A different example might make my intentions clearer.